# Eloquent advanced where within an advanced join

Tags: sql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to do the following join:

```
Schedules::select()
     ->leftJoin('histories', function ($j)
        {
            $j->on('histories.schedule_id', '=', 'schedules.id')
                ->where('histories.test', '=', DB::raw('schedules.test'))
                ->where(function ($q)
                {
                    $q->where('histories.order_id', '=', 'schedules.order_id')
                        ->orWhere('histories.customer_id', '=', DB::raw('schedules.customer_id'));
                });
        });
```

When I do, Laravel reports the error:

```
Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::where()
```

How do I structure this query in Eloquent syntax so that I get the equivalent of the following for the join statement?

```
left join histories
    on histories.schedule_id = schedules.id
        and histories.test = schedules.test
        and (
            histories.order_id = schedules.order_id
            or histories.customer_id = schedules.customer_id
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `JoinClause`s `where` doesn't work like ordinary `where` clause, and you can't pass closure for nested wheres, so you just need to repeat part of your conditions.

Also, you don't need `where` and `DB::raw` for your additional join clauses, instead use `on` once again.

So basically you need this:

```
$j->on('histories.schedule_id', '=', 'schedules.id')
  ->on('histories.test', '=', 'schedules.test')
  ->on('histories.order_id', '=', 'schedules.order_id')

  ->orOn('histories.schedule_id', '=', 'schedules.id')
  ->on('histories.test', '=', 'schedules.test')
  ->on('histories.customer_id', '=', 'schedules.customer_id');
```